# Centering button in image with CSS

Tags: html, css

I need to center a button inside an image using CSS but I am not able to center the button with respect to the top left corner of the image

Here is the page

http://jsfiddle.net/3j5w5v7f/

HTML file:

```
<div class="content">
    <img class="mainImage" src="http://mintywhite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/fond-ecran-wallpaper-image-arriere-plan-hd-29-HD.jpg" alt="logo">

    <div id="startButton">
            <button onclick="hide()" width="40px">Start Now</button>
    </div>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content{
    position: relative;
}

img.mainImage{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 400px;
    max-height: 500px;
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 1;
}
#startButton{
     position: absolute;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     top: 0px;
     left: 0px;
     z-index: 2;
}

body{
     background-image: url('http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/colorful-triangles-background.jpg');
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}
```

I need something that acts like the button "Download Whataspp" here at
http://www.whatsapp.com/

I need a button that acts like that one when you re-size the window, ie it doesn't move with respect to its background image

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3j5w5v7f/2/ ..is this what you are looking for ? ..or let me know where do you want the button to be

Comment: If you center it, like it would like to be, using coordinates, it isn't exactly what you need http://jsfiddle.net/3j5w5v7f/5/

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you want the start button positioned in respect to #mainImage?

Comment: I edited my answer below but here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3j5w5v7f/8/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated jsfiddle based on what you provided: http://jsfiddle.net/3j5w5v7f/8/

I added a div to declare the width (matching the image) and centering that div (think of it as a container). Then the button itself gets a position of absolute and proper left/top to adjust it to where you want it to be.

CSS:

```
#button-center { 
    z-index: 2;
position: absolute;
top: -101px;
left: 0px;
}

#startButton { 
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="startButton">
  <div id="button-center">
    <button onclick="hide()" width="40px">Start Now</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, I interpreted it as "how can I absolutely center a button on top of an image." In which case, you're going to want to give the containing element `relative` positioning and then set negative top and left margins on the button to half the width/height of the button, like this:

```
#mainImage {
    position:relative;
}
#startButton{
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin-left:-33px;
    margin-top:-9px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3j5w5v7f/4/)

Answer (score 0):

put another wrapper DIV around both the image and the button http://jsfiddle.net/3j5w5v7f/

HTML

```
<div class="content">
    <div id="imageButtonWrapper">
            <div id="mainImage">
                <img class="mainImage" src="http://mintywhite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/fond-ecran-wallpaper-image-arriere-plan-hd-29-HD.jpg" alt="logo">
            </div>
            <div id="startButton">
                <button onclick="hide()" width="40px">Start Now</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#mainLogo{
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}

.content{
    position: relative;
}

#imageButtonWrapper{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 400px;
    max-height: 500px;
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 1;
}
#startButton{
    position: absolute;
    left: 65px;
    top: 110px;
}

body{
    background-image: url('http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/colorful-triangles-background.jpg');
    margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not use `.content` as the wrapper div?

Comment: i thought they might have more content not just the image and button

Answer (score 0):

Create positioning like this

```
#startButton{
    position: absolute;
    top:50%; // middle
    left:50%; // center
    margin-left:-40px; // half of width of button
    z-index: 2;
    width:80px;
}
```

Width is pointed out, 'cause to see how much /about/ size it takes;... so easier to understand margin-left;
Also some negative margin top could be added
http://jsfiddle.net/3j5w5v7f/7/